# Property 'min' does not exist on type 'typeof Validators'

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a reactive form where I used validators to validate my input. below is my code and my angular is in version 4.1.3 as well as @angular/form.

```
createForm() {
this.trainee = new Trainee(null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
this.traineeForm = this.fb.group({
  firstRow: this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    gender: ['',Validators.required]
  }),
  secondRow: this.fb.group({
    cgpa: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(3)]],
    university: ['', Validators.required]
  }),
  thirdRow: this.fb.group({
    course_division: [this.trainee.course_division, Validators.required],
    course: [this.trainee.course, Validators.required]
  }),
  forthRow: this.fb.group({
    batch: [this.trainee.batch, Validators.required]
  })
})}
```

However, I can't use the Validators.min(3) as the error shows:

> Property 'min' does not exist on type 'typeof Validators'.
>   I don't really know why I cannot use it. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [no such method in Validators](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.1.3/packages/forms/src/validators.ts) in the old version of Angular you're using. Implement it yourself or, much better, upgrade. The current stable version is 6.0.7.

Note that min() validates if a number has a minimum value, and you're initializing your control with `''`, which is not a number. Maybe you want minLength. But anyway, you should upgrade.